# Revert unicode escape encoding in string (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, escaping, encode

I have a string `my_string` which holds a newline character. So, if printed it will introduce a new line.

Initially, I do `my_string.encode('unicode_escape').decode("utf-8")`

where `print(my_string.encode('unicode_escape').decode("utf-8"))` gives `\n`

and `print (repr(my_string))` gives `'\\n'`.

Then, want I want to do is convert it back to its original state so that it prints the newline, i.e. `my_string` not to display the newline character `\n` or `\\n` but simply introduce a new line.

I searched for `encode` and `decode` but could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're first encoding with unicode_escape, then decoding with utf-8, the inverse operation would be the inverse of the individual operations, in reverse order:

```
>>> x = '\n'
>>> y = x.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')
>>> y.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
'\n'
```

(The socks/shoes principle: You first put on your socks and then your shoes; to undo that you first remove your shoes and then your socks.)